# Flattening a UV-island after UV unwrapping

Tags: modeling, uv, uv-image-editor

I have a very simple 3d model (quasi-3d) that I need to unwrap and then the islands need to be flattened into rectangular shapes. I imported an *.stl file, then I unwrapped it along a single seam. In the UV Editing, I saw my model was meshed with triangular faces. I then selected "Face->Tris to quads" to get quad faces. Even then I was left with some triangular faces. At any case, I then selected a quad roughly at the center of an island, scaled all the sides to zero, and then selected "Follow Active Quads." But it's not giving me the expected flattened geometry. How do I resolve this issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As you put it, it's a very simple model... so my first question would be: do you need all this messed up geometry or would yout get along with less?

Comment: Try to imagine the box, cut it like your seam and now try to flat it on the ground... you will see that it is not possible without another cuts or tears, that way tells you that this is really not going to work without some kind of distortion or messed up texture due to all random cuts in your mesh... I would suggest you to make your mesh more simple with fewer faces and then cut along edges, not in the middle of the mesh

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann My ultimate goal is to overlay some data (say by color mapping) from some simulation results onto the islands. Maybe I could do away with the middle plane that's between the two flat planes on both sides.

Comment: @MikoCG I am okay with distortion as long as all the points maintain their relative positions. By distortion I am understanding maybe a perfect square gets stretched/shrunk with some changes in the side lengths and/or some angles get changes etc. I am fine with that. What I'm trying to say is that say there's a rectangular mold and I am trying to stretch the islands to fill that.